# Remove numbers and keep underscore from string in C++

Tags: c++, string, std

I have this piece of code but it outputs 
`Hello World` without underscore. If I want to output `Hello_World`, how can I do this?

```
string s = "Hello_World 1 2";
s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !isalpha(c); } ), s.end());
```

Comment: Start by clearly stating which characters you want to keep, then turn that description into code. You’re halfway there.

Comment: `return !isalpha(c) && c != '_';`?

Comment: You have a lambda function in it. Learn what a lambda function is and how it's syntax is and you will be able to do it on your own. (Although those are not necessary the best to learn as a beginner - but you should always try to understand the could you use in any case.)

Comment: Relevant once again: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the certain output by adding another condition to the `std::remove_if` function.

```
std::string s = "Hello_World 1 2";
s.erase( std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(),  [](char c) 
                       { 
                           return !isalpha(c) && c != '_';
                       }), 
                       s.end());
std::cout << s;
```